# get the arrayDisplay()_fucntion to print to screen, an already populated array with srand().

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

/*global constant array size*/
#define SIZE 10

/*prototyping*/
void displayArray(int *a);

int main()
{
   int numbers[SIZE];
   int x,inner,outer,temp;
```

This is to generate random values for the array elements.

```
   /*populate the array*/
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //seed randomizer
   for(x=0;x<SIZE;x++)
   {
      numbers[x] = (rand() % 1000) + 1; //display random numbers between 1-
                                          1000
   }

   /*display the unsorted array*/
   displayArray(numbers);
```

This is the bubble sort and I call the function arrayDisplay to output the swap at each step till sorted.

```
   /*sort the array*/
   for(outer=0;outer<SIZE;outer++)
   {
      for(inner=outer+1;inner<SIZE;inner++)
      {
         if(numbers[outer] > numbers[inner])
         {
            temp = numbers[inner];
            numbers[inner] = numbers[outer];
            numbers[outer] = temp;
            arrayDisplay(numbers);
         }
      }
   }
   /*display the sorted array*/
   displayArray(numbers);

   return 0;
}
```

This is the function displayArray() that should just display the random values through rand when called.

```
void displayArray(int *a){
    int x;

    for(x=0;x<SIZE;x++)
    {
        printf("%4d",x+1);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return;
}
```

The output im getting from this function is 1 - 10 as the element values instead of the random values that should be displayed, where am i going wrong?

Comment: 1. If you tell it to `printf("%4d", x+1);` it prints `x+1`. If you intend to print `a[x]` instead, you should tell that: e.g. `printf("%4d", a[x]);`. 2. Btw. are you aware that C arrays store its first element with index 0? I wouldn't ask but the `x+1` looks a bit suspicious...

Comment: I always start printing from the 1 -10, its was out of habit! Thank you for your help Scheff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `displayArray` function: if the second parameter of `printf` is `x+1`, it will print:

> 1 2 3 ... 10

you should change `printf` and use the `a` pointer:

```
printf("%4d",a[x]);
```

Comment: Thank you Luca, I understand this better! Cheers.